# Python SKLearn: Logistic Regression Probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using the Python SKLearn module to perform logistic regression. I have a dependent variable vector `Y` (taking values from 1 of M classes) and independent variable matrix `X` (with N features). My code is

```
        LR = LogisticRegression()
        LR.fit(X,np.resize(Y,(len(Y))))
```

My question is, what does `LR.coef_` and `LR.intercept_` represent. I initially thought they held the values `intercept(i)` and `coef(i,j)` s.t.

```
log(p(1)/(1-p(1))) = intercept(1) + coef(1,1)*X1 + ... coef(1,N)*XN
.
.
.
log(p(M)/(1-p(M))) = intercept(M) + coef(M,1)*X1 + ... coef(M,N)*XN
```

where `p(i)` is the probability that observation with features `[X1, ... ,XN]` is in class `i`. However when I try to convert

```
V = X*LR.coef_.transpose()
U = V + LR.intercept_
A = np.exp(U)
A/(1+A)
```

so that `A` is the matrix of `p(1) ... p(M)` for the observations in `X`. This should be the same value as

```
LR.predict_proba(X)
```

however they are close, but different. Why is this?

Comment: If you let `P = A/(1+A)`, is `P / P.sum(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))` exactly the same as `predict_proba`'s output?

Comment: Bingo, didn't think to test the probability values added to 1... Thanks, if you post this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Doesn't logistic regression estimate just one set of (N+1) coefficients? i.e. why do you have "coef(1,1)" and "coef(M,1)" if they're the same thing?
Am I missing something?

Comment: To be more precise I could have said "Multinomial Logistic Regression". The key point is that there are multiple possible classes or observation can be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes represent what you think, your probability calculations are off because you forgot to normalize: after

```
P = A / (1 + A)
```

you should do

```
P /= P.sum(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
```

to reproduce the [scikit-learn algorithm](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L230).